# 2D Array Index Out of Bounds Exception

Tags: java, android, eclipse, multidimensional-array

I am new to 2D Arrays, and while I think I understand it, I am unsure why I am getting this Index Out of Bounds Exception.  I tried making the map size 70x100, and I still received the same error.  It seems to think I am searching for the index -1156638823, which I do not understand why.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
public int rand(int i) {
    return new Random(i).nextInt();
}

public void createMap() {
    map = new Grid[7][10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            map[i][j] = new Grid(false, false, false, false, false, false,
                    false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false,
                    false, false);
        }
    }
    map[rand(7)][0] = new Grid(true, false, true, true, false, true, false,
            false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, true);
    map[rand(7)][rand(10)] = new Grid(true, false, false, false, false,
            false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false,
            false, false);
}
```

---

LOGCAT

```
05-07 19:29:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1532): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-07 19:29:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1532): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.evorlor.dungeonmaster/com.evorlor.dungeonmaster.DM}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=7; index=-1156638823
05-07 19:29:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
05-07 19:29:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-07 19:29:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-07 19:29:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
05-07 19:29:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-07 19:29:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-07 19:29:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-07 19:29:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-07 19:29:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-07 19:29:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-07 19:29:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-07 19:29:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-07 19:29:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1532): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=7; index=-1156638823
05-07 19:29:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at com.evorlor.dungeonmaster.DM.createMap(DM.java:101)
05-07 19:29:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at com.evorlor.dungeonmaster.DM.initialize(DM.java:19)
05-07 19:29:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-07 19:29:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-07 19:29:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at sofia.internal.events.EventDispatcher$MethodTransformer.invoke(EventDispatcher.java:474)
05-07 19:29:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at sofia.internal.events.EventDispatcher.invokeTransformer(EventDispatcher.java:136)
05-07 19:29:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at sofia.internal.events.EventDispatcher.dispatch(EventDispatcher.java:109)
05-07 19:29:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at sofia.app.internal.ScreenMixin.invokeInitialize(ScreenMixin.java:561)
05-07 19:29:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at sofia.app.Screen.onCreate(Screen.java:186)
05-07 19:29:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
05-07 19:29:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
05-07 19:29:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
05-07 19:29:00.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1532):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are misusing `Random`.  You have invoked the [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random%28long%29) constructor that sets the initial seed to a specific value: `i`.  But it does not restrict the random values that come back.

The [`nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28%29) method returns a random, unrestricted `int`.

You need the following code:

```
public int rand(int i) {
    return new Random().nextInt(i);
}
```

The [`nextInt(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) method restricts the random integers returned to the range `0` to `i - 1`.  Also, the parameterless `Random` constructor uses the system time to generate a different random seeding (and thus different random numbers) each time.

Random numbers in Java using `Random` are pseudo-random - they are deterministic but they require a seed to get started.  Using the same seed will get you the same random number back.  That's why it's important to use different seeds each time, and the parameterless `Random` constructor handles that for you.

In addition, you don't need to be creating another `Random` object each time your `rand` object is called.  You could create it as an instance variable in your class and just refer to it in your `rand` method.

Answer (score 4):

`new Random(i).nextInt()` doesn't do what you think it does.

You should use:

```
new Random(seed).nextInt(i)
```

Your version just initialises the seed but `nextInt()` return an integer in the whole range, if you want a smaller range you need to specify it, by specifying `nextInt(i)` you will get a value in `[0,1)`

Comment: well dont i feel foolish! what is (seed) in your code? does it matter if i dont include it?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter, in documentation of `Random()`: __Creates a new random number generator. This constructor sets the seed of the random number generator to a value very likely to be distinct from any other invocation of this constructor.__ The seed is used to let the pseudo random sequence start from a random point otherwise every time you start the same PRNG you would get same results.

Comment: excellent ty! both you and regettman gave excellent answers, so i checked the time. he beat you by about 20 seconds, so green checkmark to him. thank you very much though!!

Comment: Don't worry, I'm here to help not just to farm reputation.

Comment: As am I.  You may accept the answer that helped you the most, whichever one that is.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `Random` constructor wrong. The parameter in it is a seed. Not a maximum number it will generate.

You can read about what a seed is for example here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed

If you need it to generate numbers from 0 to X, you need to provide the X to the `nextInt` method.

```
new Random().nextInt(X);
```

Answer (score 0):

You used the wrong method: `Random#nextInt()`. You thought you used [`Random#nextInt(bound)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) instead, which yields the random integer within the range `0` (incl.) - `bound` (excl.). The integer in `Random` constructor is just a random seed.